# Summing out over custom axes

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Starting with an `Array` `arr`, and a `List` of axes `lst` of length `k`, what's a good way to sum out values over axes specified in `lst`? When `lst={1,2,...,m}`, this would be the same as `Nest[Total,arr,m]`

Example:

```
arr = Array[a, {2, 3, 4}];
```

Then `f[arr,{1}]` would have dimensions `{3,4}`, `f[arr,{2}]` will have dimensions `{2,4}`, `f[arr,{2,3}]` will have dimensions `{2}`, `f[arr,{1,2,3}]` will have head `Plus` and dimensions `{}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `Fold[Total[#, {#2}]&, arr, lst]` do what you want?

**UPDATE**

How about this?

```
f[arr_, lst_] :=
  Fold[Total[#, {#2}] &, arr, Sort[lst, Greater]]
```

*(and a tip o' the hat to @belisarius =) )*

Comment: Not quite, it's not the same as `Nest[Total,arr,k]` when `lst=Range[k]`, added some more examples

Comment: Deleted my answer to think ... tnx for your comments!

Comment: if we sort indexes beforehand I think the Fold with the i++ is right

Comment: If you sort them in descending order, do you need the `i++` at all?

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
f[arr_, coords_] :=
 With[{perm = 
    Ordering[
     Join[coords, Complement[Range[TensorRank[arr]], coords]]]},
  Total[Transpose[arr, perm], Length[coords]]
  ]
```